# Spring: Programmatically bind object from request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there a way to programmatically bind form data to an object knowing the class type? I thought there would be something like

```
T instance = something.pleaseDoSomeMagicBind(class, request)
```

somewhere or something similar, but I had no luck so far.

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to Sotirios (you saved my sanity) hint, I've been able to achieve what I've been looking for and I'm leaving here my findings if anyone else is interested

```
final WebDataBinder binder = new WebDataBinder(BeanUtils.instantiate(clazz));
ServletRequestParameterPropertyValues values = new ServletRequestParameterPropertyValues(request);
binder.bind(values);
final BindingResult result = binder.getBindingResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring binds form data by mapping request parameters to fields of instances of handler method parameter types based on matching names.

```
.../asd?someValue=123
```

will be bound to an instance of

```
public class Backing {
    private String someValue;
    //getters and setters
}
```

assuming you have a request handler like

```
@RequestMapping
public String handle(Backing backing) {
     return backing.getSomeValue(); // "123"
}
```

Nothing exists like what you are describing.

Comment: Unfortunately the place I need that functionality in is not a controller and I don't know at compile time the type of the backing object.

Comment: @MatteoRolla Check the `WebDataBinder` class for hints, but, as far as I know, the functionality you're looking for doesn't exist out of the box.